# Google sheet moving cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

i have google sheet with 9108 rows that follow certain order , but i strugling with moving 2nd row next to first and 3rd next to other ( picture down below ), i cant just take all 9thousand rows and just split it to 3 thousand columns, i trying to find script solution like this :

move every other row next to row before
move every row after moved row next "other" row
remove blank rows

and do it with all rows in sheet without destroying order

[image: Picture with example]

thanks anybody for helping or finding solution.

edit:

This works how i need, but it creates columns and with 9108 rows it stops after 100 rows because there are too many cells.

```
function Test() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var ss = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet()

  var index = 1
  var rowSpan = 1
  var columnSpan = 1

  while (index <= ss.getLastRow()) {
    ss.getRange(index, 1, 1, index + 1).moveTo(ss.getRange(rowSpan, columnSpan))
    columnSpan = columnSpan + 3

    if (columnSpan == 13) {
      columnSpan = 1
      rowSpan++
    }

    index++
  }
}
```

Comment: Case closed, found the answer. thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with this function:

```js
function Test() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var ss = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet()
  
  var index = 1
  var rowSpan = 1
  var columnSpan = 1
  var value
  
  while (index <= ss.getLastRow()) {
    
    value = ss.getRange(index, 1).getValue()
    
    ss.getRange(rowSpan, columnSpan).setValue(value)
    
    columnSpan++
      
    if (columnSpan == 4) {
      columnSpan = 1
      rowSpan++
    }
    
    index++
 }
}
```

You can register a new macro and then copy/paste the content of this function inside of it.

After that, you can clear extra data you don't need.

Comment: Thank you it worked how i expected it should work, however i had to modife it little bit like so:
`code`while (index <= ss.getLastRow()) {
    
    ss.getRange(index, 1).moveTo(ss.getRange(rowSpan, columnSpan))
    
    columnSpan = columnSpan + 4
      
    if (columnSpan == 13) {
      columnSpan = 1
      rowSpan++
    }`code`

but i still cant figure out how to move 3 cells and not just one

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really understand your problem. Could you explain me in another way?

Comment: Sorry , i mean right now it move "A2" to "D1" but i need to move "A2:C2" to "D1:F1" i hope this help, i also uploaded picture and there you can see it better that its in fact 3 cells and not one